# Using TFS 2018 to deploy build to an exist website

Tags: tfs

I just set up a new TFS CI/CD process for an existing project. How do I set up the release so it would deploy to the existing Site folder in the IIS instead of the Application Pool? Using TFS 2018 release management process. This is not an azure pipeline project

Comment: HI Charlston Manning, could you explain more clear about `this is not an azure pipeline project ` Azure pipeline is just build definition or release definition. Not related to project. What's your project type, asp.net?

Comment: Yea is it an asp.net project. I am using on site servers to host the website. I am using the tfs CI/CD process and was on the release part need to know is there a deployment step that would allow me to stop and restart the app pool before I update the website

Comment: Hi Charlston Manning, Sorry for the later response. Have update my reply. You could directly specify the exist website name in the IIS Web App Deploy task. Details please check my reply.

Comment: Hi Charlston Manning, just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you have any other concern.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, you just need to specify the existing **Website name** in [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) step, then it will automatically update the website once any changes are checked in with the CI/CD definitions set.

Assuming the Website name is **ApplicationToDeploy**, just specify the name under `Deployment > Website name`

[image]

Just need to make sure the website is existing there, you could  check this info in IIS manager.

[image]